# ActionScript 3.0 CurrentLabel not working on Loaded .SWF file

Tags: actionscript, adobe

I am trying to get this to work for ages but doesnt seem to work out quite well
this is my code:

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.display.Loader;
import flash.net.URLRequest;

var cola:Loader;

        cola = new Loader()
        cola.load(new URLRequest("resources/colabar.swf"));
        this.addChild(cola);
        //cola.currentLabel = "frame1";
```

This works. The .swf is in my stage now. Moving from frame to frame.

Obiously, when deleting the // its not working. And ill get this error message: 1119: Access of possibly undefined property currentLabel through a reference with static type flash.display:Loader.

Comment: Have you tried type-casting  your loader to a MovieClip? Otherwise you won't be able to use MC-methods.

Comment: I've added this:  var MC:MovieClip  MC.addChild(cola) and I am getting the same error. Removing the // again makes me have no .SWF in my stage.

Comment: I was thinking about doing  'MovieClip(cola).currentLabel = "frame1";'

Comment: When I use that, I am getting a new error: 1059: Property is read-only. I guess we're 1 step closer :p

Comment: Well, it's already telling you what to do, right? I don't exactly know what you're after but did you know that you can pass a label name to .gotoAndPlay() ?

Comment: I think I am doing something really wrong, Im getting this: TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert flash.display::Loader@26eb6741 to flash.display.MovieClip.

Comment: @Cryingsoul You need to grab `Loader.content`, but for that you need to let the SWF load. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
cola.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, colaCompleteHandler);

...

function colaCompleteHandler(event:Event):void
{
    var loader:Loader = LoaderInfo(event.target).loader;
    var mc:MovieClip = loader.content as MovieClip;

    if (mc) {
        mc.gotoAndPlay("frame1");
    }
}
```

i.e. wait for the SWF to load, then set the label.

Comment: I am getting this when I add that code: 1180: Call to a possibly undefined method LoaderInfo.

Comment: @Cryingsoul `import flash.display.LoaderInfo`.